# How to deal with duplicates using python/mysql?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a sql query which returns a list of duplicates with their id, from my table Person :

```
1   hudson
43  hudson
67  hudson
34  roger
79  roger
89  kerry
403 kerry
```

Using a Python script, I would like to automate this kind of query, for example for the "hudson" case :

```
UPDATE Customer SET person_id = 1 WHERE person_id = 43;
```

When the number of duplicates is set (for example 2), I think we can do something like :

```
cursor.execute(*myquery that returns list of duplicates*)
rows=cursor.fetchmany(2)
row1=rows[1] #??
row2=rows[2] #??
cursor.execute('UPDATE Customer SET person_id = row1[0] WHERE person_id = row2[0];')
```

I really don't know how to do when the number of duplicates is variable.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: If the person name is unique, then why not use it as the WHERE predicate?  Example:  `UPDATE Customer SET person_id = 1 WHERE name = 'hudson'`

Comment: @AJ. from his example it's obvious name is not unique

Comment: They're trying to merge together records that have the same name, was my understanding.  So name may not be unique, but I thought the goal was to MAKE it unique after the merge.

Answer (score 0):

Group by the names and select the minimum person ID from each group.

Also consider using [Python Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and just dumping all of the data into a Pandas DataFrame, then you can just use the `drop_duplicates` function. I've found it was well worth my effort to create my own SQL-to-h5 and SQL-to-Pandas backend code to let me just do all my Python work in Pandas and never mess with the SQL directly.